# CSS page content in rendered PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I am rendering a page into a PDF document and am using @page @bottom-left to add text in the bottom left.

```
@page {size: portrait A4;
 @bottom-left {content: "Some text to show bottom left. Some more text";font-size: 7pt;font-family: "Verdana";color: #cccccc;}
}
```

This works fine, however what I want to do is have a line break as below:
Some text to show bottom left. 
Some more text

Have tried `<br>, <p>, \n, \r` all of which appear as text. 
Tried `&#10;` but that stop the styling from working altogether.
Is this possible to do, and is so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Authors may include newlines in the generated content by writing the "\A" escape sequence in one of the strings after the 'content' property. This inserted line break is still subject to the 'white-space' property. 
>   [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content)

use \00000a  or \A

```
 content: 'Some text to show bottom left. \A Some more text';
```

Css:

```
 white-space: pre;
```

Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZULug/1/)